# is it possible to format / reflow html in rubymine?

Tags: html, rubymine

Is it possible to format or reindent html in RubyMine 3.2.4? I tried `Code... Reformat Code` but it doesn't seem to do anything for HTML. Do I need a plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work.

Using the standard 404.html file that is generated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #666; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
    div.dialog {
      width: 25em;
      padding: 0 4em;
      margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right-color: #999;
      border-bottom-color: #999;
    }
    h1 { font-size: 100%; color: #f00; line-height: 1.5em; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This file lives in public/404.html -->
  <div class="dialog">
    <h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>
    <p>You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I used the Code/Reformat option and it resulted in the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #666;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        }

        div.dialog {
            width: 25em;
            padding: 0 4em;
            margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-right-color: #999;
            border-bottom-color: #999;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 100%;
            color: #f00;
            line-height: 1.5em;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This file lives in public/404.html -->
<div class="dialog">
    <h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>

    <p>You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see how it reformatted the styles in particular (and if I change the line breaks, etc., it fixes those as well).

If you go to File/Settings, IDE Settings/Editor, then make sure the option Show "Reformat Code" Dialog box is checked [x], try it again. It might be set to only fix selected text? Or ...

Comment: I see that you are right. I was expecting something a little more like VS does; RubyMine isn't as aggressive as VS is when it comes to cleaning up whitespace.

Comment: Agreed. I like the VS one a bit better generally, especially as there is more control.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ⌘ + ⌥ + l for keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the html formatting options on "Project Settings > Code Style > HTML".

For instance: you could change the tab size, indentation, etc.

If you are on OSx you could use the shortcut ⌘ + ,

Other suggestion: try renaming the file before format (removing the .erb from it)